# If $\mathbb{P}$ is an infinite notion of forcing then there is $H\subset \mathbb{P}$ such that $M[H]$ is not a model of ZFC.

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, forcing

I am trying to prove the following statement and i think i have reached a proof but i'm not sure, is my proof correct or have i missed something?
If $M$ is a countable transitive model of ZFC and $\mathbb{P} \in M$ is an infinite notion of forcing then there exists an $H \subset \mathbb{P}$ such that $M[H]$ is not a model of ZFC. Hint: Fix $f\in M$ such that $f$ maps $\omega \times \omega$ one-to-one  into $\mathbb{P}$. Choose $H$ such that $f^{-1}(H)$ is a well-order of type $\alpha \gt o(M) = \text{Ord} \cap M$.
My proof: Fix $H$ as in the hint. Since we construct $M[H]$ using $\mathbb{P}$-names and we don't nessecarily need $H$ to be $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$ for the construction, we know that $M[H]$ is a transitive set and that $\text{Ord} \cap M = \text{Ord} \cap M[H]$. Now if we suppose $M[H]$ is a model of ZFC, since $H\in M[H]$ and $f \in M[H]$ then $f^{-1}(H) \in M[H]$ and it is a theorem of ZFC that every well-ordered set is isomorphic to a unique ordinal, so $f^{-1}(H) \cong \beta$ for some $\beta \in \text{Ord}^{M[H]}$. But looking from the outside we see that $\beta \cong \alpha$ for the $\alpha$ in the hint, so $\beta = \alpha$. Now since $\text{Ord} \cap M = \text{Ord} \cap M[H]$ we have $\alpha \in o(M)$ which is a contradiction.
Since this is my first exercise in forcing i am trying to be very careful, i would be very happy if you could point out any error, even small ones.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: That looks good to me. The only thing you may want to explicitly mention is that all transitive models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ do compute the correct order type, i.e. $\mathrm{otp}^{M}(f^{-1}(H)) = \alpha$.

Comment: @StefanMesken, Is it enough to say that, the correct computation of the order type your saying follows from the absolutness of the notion of an ordinal for transitive models?

Comment: My edit was "cosmetic" . When I got to "$f$ maps $\omega\times \omega$ $1-1$", at first I thought that "$\omega \times \omega$ $1-1$"  was  the domain and maybe a typo. So I just wanted to make it easier to read,

Comment: @ShervinSorouri No, that doesn't suffice. To see an example why: Transitive models can compute cardinals incorrectly even though all of them agree that cardinals are ordinals. You really need to know that order types are computed correctly (which is an easy exercise in case you don't already know this fact).

Comment: @StefanMesken, We have $\text{otp}^{M}X = \alpha \leftrightarrow \exists f(f \text{ is a bijection} \wedge \text{dom}(f) = M \wedge \text{ran}(f) = \alpha)$, So $\text{otp}^{M}X = \alpha$ is $\Sigma_1$. Now if $\text{otp}^{M}X = \beta$ for some $\beta \neq \alpha$. We have $\text{otp}X = \beta = \alpha$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Your claimed characterization of order type is incorrect. Here is a correct one ($R$ is a well-order): $\mathrm{otp} (R) = \alpha \iff (\exists f( f \colon (\mathrm{dom}(R);R)  \to (\alpha; \in) \wedge \alpha \in \mathrm{Ord} \wedge f \text{ is an isomorphism}) \iff \forall f ( \ldots)$ showing that it is $\Delta_{1}$. (The $\ldots$ is for you to fill in.)

Comment: @StefanMesken, Oh i see i have used otp a little bit awkwardly, by $\text{otp}X$ i meant the order type of the relation on the set $X$. For the $\Pi_1$ part can we say $\forall f \forall \beta((\beta \text{ is an ordinal} \wedge f:(\text{dom}(R), R) \rightarrow (\beta, \in) \wedge f \text{is an isomorphism}) \rightarrow \alpha = \beta)$ ?

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Yes, that works.